# Modifying page layout TD width

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, css, 2016

I am currently using a page layout that has 3 columns with a header and footer. When I use inspect element I see a table with #layoutsTable. The first TR is the header, then on the second TR the TD's all have widths specified via inline css.

```
<td style="width: 33.3%"></td>
<td class="ms-wiki-columnSpacing" style="width: 60%"></td>
<td class="ms-wiki-columnSpacing" style="width: 33.3%"></td>
```

I've tried overiding the widths using a Script Editor web part and using !important. Tried different CSS styles. Nothing seems to work. My goal is to decrease that 50% in the 2nd cell.

```
.ms-wiki-columnSpacing {width: 33.3%!important}
```

Also tried using nth child:

```
#layoutsTable TBODY TR:nth-child(2) TD {width: 33.3% !important;}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I create a new page layout that does not have inline css width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ordering rules of CSS is complex to start with, and to use `!important` makes it even harder. You can read more about it in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459093/286244) to the question "In which order do CSS stylesheets override?"

In your case I'd create the page layout you need, and avoid inline CSS.

Comment: thanks I’ll create a new layout with no specified width.